# Get a key from a dictionary safely in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'd have a library with a single function to safely get a key from a dictionary.  Is this possible inside a test suite?

```
def safe_get(dict_obj, key):
    val = dict_obj.get(key)
    if val is None:
        val = {}
    return val
```

Is there a way to do this using something like `Run_Keyword_If` or `Set_Variable_If`?

Comment: What should be "possible inside a test suite" and what want you to do using `Run Keyword If` or `Set Variable If`?

Comment: Also, do you need just the key or do you need the value associated with that key as well? I'm presuming you'll ultimately aim to get the value, correct?

Comment: @Alex.S I mean inside the robot test file with nothing external dependencies.

Comment: @ash9209 I want the value for that key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Assuming you're using robot 2.9 or later, you can call the `get` method on the dictionary by using the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword, which will allow you to specify a default value when the key doesn't exist.

For example:

```
| | ${data}=  | create dictionary | ...
| | ${value}= | evaluate          | $data.get("some key", "default value")
```

### Explanation

Starting with robotframework 2.9 you can directly access variables in expressions by removing the curly braces (see [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) library documentation). For example, if you have a dictionary named `${data}`, you can use the actual variable in an expression with `$data`.

This makes it very easy to use variables in python expressions. For example, if you want to provide a default for when a dictionary doesn't have a key you can call the `get` method of the dictionary by using the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword with something like `$data.get(...)`.

Note also that robot defines the variable `${None}` to be the python value `None` (*not* the string `"None"`), which you can use in an expression for checking to see whether a value is `None`.

The following examples show how to use `evaluate` to call the `get` method of the dictionary. The first test shows that you can check for a `None` value, the second example shows how you can provide a default value.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Collections

*** Test Cases ***
| Get value from dictionary, returning None if key not in dictionary
| | ${data}= | Create dictionary | key1=one | key2=two
| | ${value}= | Evaluate | $data.get("key3")
| | should be equal | ${value} | ${None}

| Get value from dictionary, returning default value if key not in dictionary
| | ${data}= | Create dictionary | key1=one | key2=two
| | ${value}= | Evaluate | $data.get("key3", "default value")
| | should be equal as strings | ${value} | default value
```

Of course, if you want your default value to be a new dictionary (as implied by your question) you can do that too:

```
| | ${value}= | Evaluate | $data.get("key3", {})
```

Comment: Would `${value}=   Set_Variable   ${data.get("some key")}` be preferred?

Comment: @CharlesL.: _preferred_? Not necessarily. I'm not sure there is a preferred way.

Comment: I ask b/c eval is generally frowned upon in python, but I'm not sure what mechanism ${data.get()} is using.

Comment: @CharlesL.: if this is a test where you control the data, it's perfectly safe. If you're really concerned about it, you can write a keyword in python, or string together a whole bunch of robot keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Variables ***
&{Charles Dictionary}

*** Test Cases ***

Safely Get a Key from Dictionary

    Set To Dictionary       ${Charles Dictionary}
    ... MyInterest              Hiking
    ... YourInterest            Swimming
    Work with Interests         ${Charles Dictionary}

*** Keywords ***

Work with Interests     [Arguments]         ${Charles Dictionary}
    ${val}=     Get This Value From Dictionary      ${Charles Dictionary}       MyInterest
    Run Keyword If      '${val}'!='None'        Log     That key is present in the dictionary!          console=yes
    Run Keyword If      '${val}'=='None'        Log     That key wasn't present in the dictionary!      console=yes


Get This Value From Dictionary      [Arguments]     ${Dictionary Name}      ${Key}
    ${KeyIsPresent}=    Run Keyword And Return Status       Dictionary Should Contain Key       ${Dictionary Name}      ${Key}
    ${Value}=           Run Keyword If      ${KeyIsPresent}     Get From Dictionary             ${Dictionary Name}      ${Key}
    Return From Keyword         ${Value}
```

Here, `Charles Dictionary` is a dictionary name that I've declared in the `Variables` section. I set 2 key-value pairs to it, call a keyword `Work with Interests`, and pass this dictionary as an argument to it.

The `Work with Interests` keyword gets values from the dictionary, allowing for both None and not-None values.

If a dictionary has the key present in it, the variable `val` will get the associated value for that key. If the dictionary **does NOT** have that key, the variable `val` will get a value of `None`.

I have also illustrated how can you can handle None and not None values in order to call different keywords. I've used the `Log` keyword to illustrate, but really, you can call any keyword you like, a built-in keyword or your own custom keyword.

I hope this helps you. If it does not, please do let me know.

Comment: If the value is None, how can you set it to an empty dictionary?  I was having trouble with that because the `Run Keyword If` and `Set Variable If` were always setting None for me on the false case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that perfectly. Could you rephrase? I'm assuming you need to know what if you don't want to pass a value to the keyword? If this is the case, just don't set the key and it's value in the dictionary. From the keyword, if you get the value for that key, it will retrieve it as None and then if the condition for None is satisfied you can call whatever keyword you need.

Comment: This has an error -- if the value of the dictionary of the literal string `None` it will treat it as if it doesn't exist. For example, change `Hiking` to `None`.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your example -- you need two or more spaces following `...`.

Comment: I have a large dict (full record) with keys that can be dicts (`author` has `email` & `name`).  I have keywords to set fields, like setting `author.email`.  I want to have a keyword to get a field that is either an existing dict, or an empty dict when either the key isn't there *OR* the value is `None`.  Then I set my field inside that dict.  So `set author email`, gets the current `author` field , or an empty dict using `Get This Value From Dictionary` then sets the email field within that.